# How do I force the font color to remain the way it is rather than changing

Tags: excel, vba

My program basically highlights the keywords in text to the user choice font color.I have a problem only when displaying the search terms in the cell that is specified by the user not in actual execution of the program. I take the terms input, range/cell to display these terms, font color from the user. This is partial code:

```
 Dim Ran As String
          searchTerms = InputBox("Please enter words to search, if more than one string seperate by comma and space", "Need Input", 1)


       Ran = InputBox("Please enter cell where you want the search terms to be displayed ideally below verbatim like C2,D2 ", "Need Input", 0, 8)
      r = Range(Ran).Row
      c = Range(Ran).Column

       If IsEmpty(Cells(r, 1)) And c <> "A" Then
         Range(Ran).Value = Range(Ran).Value & ", " & searchTerms
        Else: Range(Ran).EntireRow.Insert
        Range(Ran).Value = searchTerms
        End If

       searchTerms = Split(UCase(searchTerms), ", ")
```

This works as expected for 2 executions but for third time execution the previous execution font color changes to the 1st execution color. How do I force it to remain as it was before execution. Suppose after 1st time execution it was yellow, After Second execution the appended variables were green, Then when I am performing the third execution the whole cell content change to yellow before peforming the execution and the only the third execution terms will change to user defined font color. But the Second execution appended terms will be yellow as first execution color.
This is the code which is highlighting function:

```
Function HilightString(offSet As Integer, searchString As String, rowNum As Long, ingredCol As String, FontColor, fontSize As Integer) As Integer

        Dim x As Integer
        Dim newOffset As Integer
        Dim targetString As Variant

         If Cells(rowNum, ingredCol).HasFormula Then
Cells(rowNum, ingredCol).Value = "'" & Cells(rowNum, ingredCol).Formula
End If
        targetString = Mid(Cells(rowNum, ingredCol), offSet)
        foundPos = InStr(UCase(targetString), searchString)

        If foundPos > 0 Then

            Cells(rowNum, ingredCol).Characters(offSet + foundPos - 1, Len(searchString)).Font.ColorIndex = FontColor

            Cells(rowNum, ingredCol).Characters(offSet + foundPos - 1, Len(searchString)).Font.Size = 14

            newOffset = offSet + foundPos + Len(searchString)

            x = HilightString(newOffset, searchString, rowNum, ingredCol, FontColor, fontSize)
        Else

            Exit Function

        End If
 End Function
```

First execution highlighted turn, signal in blue and created in cell c2:[image: After 1st execution]

Second execution highlighted Rear in green It works fine till this point[image: Second execution]

Before complete third execution highlighted blink [image: Before complete 3rd execution]

After 3rd execution. The second executed words turn back to blue [image]

Comment: Seems like a lot of the relevant code is missing?  There's nothing related to color here...

Comment: Could you please at least add some screenshots to the question.

Comment: How do I save the format? I guess the value is making it to lose the format.  I guess all I need to do is save the format in this step     ` Range(Ran).Value = Range(Ran).Value & ", " & searchTerms`

Comment: @Tim Williams  How to save the font color along with value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this to add the new words:

```
Range(Ran).Value = Range(Ran).Value & ", " & searchTerms
```

you cannot preserve multiple colors of text - replacing the content will just give the whole cell the color of the first letter.  That's OK for your first and second runs, but will fail from run 3 forward.

You need to add the new text using the Characters collection, not by replacing the whole cell content.

Example:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Range("A1")

    AddTextWithColor c, "first", vbRed
    AddTextWithColor c, "second", vbBlue
    AddTextWithColor c, "third", vbGreen

End Sub

Sub AddTextWithColor(c As Range, txt As String, clr As Long)
    Dim l As Long
    With c
        If Len(.Value) = 0 Then
            .Value = txt
        Else
            l = .Characters.Count
            'adds the new text without replacing existing formatting
            .Characters(l + 1, Len(txt) + 2).Text = "," & txt
        End If
        With .Characters(IIf(l = 0, 1, l + 2), Len(txt)).Font
            .Color = clr
            .Size = 14
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Should I insert this part of code in the highlight function or before using highlight function?as I get the inputs from the user like fontcolor, or the range where I need to insert and basically this is what my highlight function is doing right?

Comment: The relevant change you need to make in your code is that to add to add content to existing content you should use the `Characters` collection (`.Characters(l + 1, Len(txt) + 2).Text = "," & txt`) instead of using something like `Range(Ran).Value = Range(Ran).Value & ", " & searchTerms`

Comment: it it possible to force "," to be black always

Comment: Yes if that's what you want - find the "," and color it/them black: by default it will inherit the color from any existing content.